# TS Lint Error; Type X is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RefAttributes<any>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm working on a React and TypeScript app, using webpack, and I'm getting the exact same error for every one of my React components. The error is always this:

`Type X is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RefAttributes<any>'`

I've been searching for a solution for 2 days now. I think there might be something off in my tsconfig.json or my webpack - both are available in the GitHub demo repo at the bottom.

**Example 1:**

Say I have this component:

```
export const Container = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <Container>
      {children}
    </Container>
  );
}
```

The error for the above component will complain about the children prop:
`TS2322: Type '{ children: Element; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RefAttributes<any>'.`

**Example 2**

Say I have this component:

```
export const Title = ({text, color}) => {
  return (
    <h1 style={{color: color}}>{text}</h1>
  );
}
```

Then the error complains about those two props:
`TS2322: Type '{ text: string; color: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RefAttributes<any>'`

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es6",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": ["../src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

**Github Example Repo:** Wannna run the code yourself?

1. `git clone https://github.com/TJBlackman/demo-tslint-error.git`
2. `cd demo-tslint-error`
3. `npm install`
4. `npm run dev`

How can I avoid these errors? When I use the Create React App TS bundler, I don't get these errors. I just want to pass some simple props!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your **tsconfig.json** use:

```
"moduleResolution": "node"
```

The issue is that the use of `"module": "es6"` appears to cause the module resolution strategy to change to classic. This is quite annoying, as this is not uniformly mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#module-resolution-strategies) (they specify this happens for `AMD | System | ES2015`, but not `es6`).

In order to avoid problems in I recommend manually specifying the module resolution strategy:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es6",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    // Explicitly force module resolution strategy to be node,
    //  to prevent "module": "es6" from changing it to classic.
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "include": ["../src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

I also created a pull request to apply this change: https://github.com/TJBlackman/demo-tslint-error/pull/1/commits/634ec9889096baca0676ddf3076c66e82addfdd8 (I'm `sliftist` on github).

Comment: >"ES6" and "ES2015" values may be used when targeting "ES5" or lower. as quoted in docs i mentioned.

Comment: That documentation on tsconfig.json is very useful, I usually just use the tsconfig.json document in the handbook, which has significantly less information. I originally wrote up an answer saying the same thing ("module": "commonJS"), as that is what all of my tsconfig.json's look like, however I realized the OP might actually want to use "ES6". The output (from TypeScript) will be slightly different (one emitting code with `export function test` the other emitting code with `export.test = function`).

Comment: Thank you both! I actually did revert to `module: "commonJS"` because I don't really need the ES6 option, but I chose this answer for it's better explanation. However, I do appreciate the links left in the other answer and I reviewed each one of them. I learned a lot and hope this thread helps others in the future.

Answer (score 1):

for more info read these docs

[Doc on what Module does](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#simple-example)

[Doc on Module options and values allowed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/en/tsconfig#module)

[Doc on webpack react basic config](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html)

use `module:"commonJS"`

> To compile, we must specify a module target on the command line. For
> Node.js, use --module commonjs; for require.js, use --module amd